# HTML table column width problem

Tags: html, css

```
<table width="825" border="0" cellspacing="1" class="tableLines1" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>     
       <td align="left" valign="middle">Account / BIC</td>
       <td align="left" valign="middle">Name</td>
       <td align="left" valign="middle">Email Address</td
   </tr>
   <tr> 
       <td ><%=Data.getAccount())%></td>
       <td ><%=Data.getName())%></td>
       <td width="250px"><%=Data.getEmailAddress())%></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following table. This data object get populated from database. The problem is when email address gets bigger the width of table also increases. For example

```
emailAddress = lolol@ghgg.fdg, jjjjjjoj@hiuh.com, jojo@hsc.comddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

then html intelligently breaks it from spaces and make three two rows like this.

```
lolol@ghgg.fdg, jjjjjjoj@hiuh.com, 
jojo@hsc.comddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

but what i want is that if emailAddress size increases a certain value table size i.e column width should remain constant.

```
lolol@ghgg.fdg, jjjjjjoj@hiuh.com, 
jojo@hsc.comdddddddddddddddddddddd
ddddddddddd
```

To be more specific i want the data to be displayed as shown above!

Can anyone please guide me. Thanks !

Edited : I want html to intelligently decide the column widths itself. Just not itself increase the table width from the specified value !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS rule: `word-wrap: break-word;`

`break-word` means the text will wrap to next line.

`word-wrap` is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari.

Comment: You need to set a fixed width to cells in order to get working this property

Comment: hmmmm. but i want html to intelligently decide the column widths itself. Just not increase the table width from the specified value !

Comment: In this way you just can't use `word-wrap` to solve your problem.

Comment: i applied it to both <td>'s i.e the heading and the data <td>'s. still not working ! :(

Comment: need to set width of all cells ? or just the email cell?

Comment: Just apply to email cells a width different from `auto`.

Comment: check out my code. 250px width was already set to email column !

Comment: Please don't set inline width, it's weird. Set it in a stylesheet.

Comment: ok got it. And you know what?! its working now ! haha. gr8 thanks man ! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try wrapping your email address in a div with overflow set to hidden or scroll

```
<td width="250px"><div style="overflow:hidden; width:100%"><%=Data.getEmailAddress())%></div></td>
```